# how to findall class using beautifulsoup when class has random offerid?

Tags: beautifulsoup

how to findall class using beautifulsoup when class has random offerid? im trying using below syntax but it don't get anything

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":xyz "})
```

class example is as below

```
<div class=abc">
<div class=bcd">
<div class="xyz " offerid="65546">
<div class="xyz " offerid="46465">
<div class="xyz " offerid="56747">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS Selector to get the items with class name.Try following example.

```
data = '''
<div class="xyz " offerid="65546">Test 1</div>
<div class="xyz " offerid="46465">Test 2</div>
<div class="xyz " offerid="56747">Test 3</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

containers = soup.select("div.xyz")
for item in containers:
    print(item.text)
```

OR

```
data = '''
<div class="xyz " offerid="65546">Test 1</div>
<div class="xyz " offerid="46465">Test 2</div>
<div class="xyz " offerid="56747">Test 3</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

containers = soup.select(".xyz")
for item in containers:
    print(item.text)
```

**EDITED:**

```
data = '''
<div class=abc">
<div class=bcd">
<div class="xyz " offerid="65546">
<div class="xyz " offerid="46465">
<div class="xyz " offerid="56747">
</div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
containers = soup.select("div.xyz[offerid]")

for item in containers:
     print(item['offerid'])
```

Comment: what is your expected output?would you like to print offterid?

Comment: findall class <div class="xyz " offerid="*">

Comment: @hk' : check my Edited answer is that you are looking after?If not please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear on your quesiton but the ID shouldn't matter if you are picking up the div via the class name. The below sample code works.

```
html = '''
<div class="xyz " offerid="65546"> sample text </div>
<div class="xyz " offerid="46465"> sample text </div>
<div class="xyz " offerid="56747"> sample text </div>
'''
soup       = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

containers = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"xyz "})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want an attribute selector

```
data = [item['offerid'] for item in soup.select('[offerid]')]
```

or

```
data = [item.text for item in soup.select('[offerid]')]
```